# Why the hadamard_product result of two square matrixs is not desired?

Tags: python, sympy, linear-algebra

I want to calculate the hamamard procduct of matrix using sympy package, and the codes are follows:

````
```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Matrix ,hadamard_product
M = [
[1, 0, 0],
[0, 1,0 ],
[0, 0, 1]
]
D = [ 10,20,30]
C= Matrix(len(M),3,len(M)*D)
A = Matrix(M)
B=hadamard_product(A,C)
print("1:",B)
A.multiply_elementwise (C)
M = [
[1, 0, 0,0],
[0, 1,0 ,0],
[0, 0, 1,0] 
]
D = [ 10,20,30,40]
C= Matrix(3,4,3*D)
A = Matrix((M))
B=hadamard_product(A,C)
print("2:",B)
```
````

The outputs are:

```
1: Matrix([[10, 20, 30], [10, 20, 30], [10, 20, 30]])
2: Matrix([[10, 0, 0, 0], [0, 20, 0, 0], [0, 0, 30, 0]])
```

But as my understanding of hadamard product, the 1st result must be:"[[10,0,0],[0,20,0],[0,0,30]]", I don't know is it a math problem or a code problem?

Comment: If you replace the expressions with B=HadamardProduct(A,C).doit() you get the correct result. This must be a bug.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/24141